# AttributeError: 'ParentedTree' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, tree, nlp, nltk, corpus

I am basically working on parsed tree and trying to annotate tree nodes dominating empty categories(Empty node annotation).

I have defined a recurvsive function as below but the error that I am getting is "AttributeError: 'ParentedTree' object has no attribute 'label'".

```
def annotateTraceNodes(node):
numChildren = len(node);
numNone=0;

    for child in node:
        if isinstance(child,Tree):
            annotateTraceNodes(child);
            if(numChildren==0 or child.label().endswith("-NONE-")):
            numNone+=1;            
    if(numChildren==numNone):
        print "setting the label";
        node.set_label(node.label()+"-NONE-");
```

Comment: There is no object in this code called `ParentedTree`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion & typo error. I have corrected the typo. How do I make things work?

Comment: There is no need for the semi-colons at the end of lines. This isn't C/C++.

Comment: Yes. I understand but that does not give an error. Just got habituated. I shall work on that & improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google suggests you're using NLTK, which I'm going to assume is the case.

A [ParentedTree](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.ParentedTree) does not have a method called `.label()`.  So when you write things like this:

```
child.label().endswith("-NONE-")
```

Python doesn't know what to do.

A [Tree](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree), on the other hand, does have a `.label()` method.  Did you perhaps use a ParentedTree instead of a Tree somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Could also be a versioning issue.

Worked for me with version 3.3

```
pip install nltk==3.3
```